# Help needed with verilog testbench

Tags: verilog, testbench

could anyone explain, why the output signal in my verilog testbench isn't changing?

I'm trying to build a module that does tasks on both posedge and negedge.
For testing purposes, I've built a module that receives a clock and returns one signal.
The signal is being set to 1 on posedge, and set to 0 on negedge- I expect it to be a copy of clock signal.
Everything is compiling and synthesizing without errors, the testbench is being run- but the output signal doesn't change, it stays at zero.
I am new to verilog, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Here is my module-

```
module mytest( clk, rst, led );
input clk, rst;
output led;

reg r_out = 1'b0;

always @ (*)
begin

    @(posedge clk)
    begin
        r_out <= 1'b1;
    end

    @(negedge clk)
    begin
        r_out <= 1'b0;
    end

end

assign led = r_out;

endmodule
```

And here is the testbench-

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
module mytest_tb;

parameter SYSCLK_PERIOD = 100;// 10MHZ
reg SYSCLK;
reg NSYSRESET;
wire w_led;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Clock Driver
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
always @(SYSCLK)
    #(SYSCLK_PERIOD / 2.0) SYSCLK <= !SYSCLK;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Instantiate Unit Under Test:  mytest
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
mytest mytest_0 (
    // Inputs
    .clk(SYSCLK),
    .rst(NSYSRESET),

    // Outputs
    .led(w_led)

    // Inouts

);

initial
begin
    SYSCLK = 1'b0;
    NSYSRESET = 1'b0;
end

endmodule
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For synthesis, you cannot have `@(*)`, `@(posedge clk)` and `@(negedge clk)` in the same always block. I'd expect an error for this; if not, there should at least be warnings. There must only be one `@` and it needs to next to `always`.

Comment: @toolic - I chose a bad example. The question is not about copying `clk` signal, it's about modifying register on both posedge and negedge. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @greg - I was told that my approach is wrong. I'll clarify with some more people and report here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was pointed out that this is a wrong approach.

The problem in question should have been solved by using a **Finite State Machine**- that would eliminate the need for additional actions on negedge.

As for the question itself- why doesn't the test work- that's because

```
always @ (*) begin
    @ (posedge clk)
        ...
    @ (negedge clk)
        ...
end
```

is incorrect syntax. Correct would be

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    ...
end
always @ (negedge clk) begin
    ...
end
```